# Kendo Grid with client template

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

This is my Telerik Grid. I want to convert it into Kendo Grid.
I have to write this code into Kendo Grid:

```
 @(Html.telerik().Grid<MDA.AppEntities.Orders.OrderList(Model.OrderList)
   .Name("GridLastOrder")
   .Columns(columns =>{ columns.Template(@<text>
   @if (item.EventTypeID == 2 || item.EventTypeID == 3)
   {
 var nurserole = new string[] { OperationRoles.Nurse.ToString() };
 if (item.EventTypeID == 2 && nurserole.Any(MDA.AppController.GlobalController.CSRRoles.Isinrole))
 {
  <a href="@Url.Action("CreateConsultation", "Operations", new { customerID = item.EventPatientID, type = item.EventTypeID, IsEdit = item.Ord_ID })">
                                    Edit/ Modify Consult
                                </a> <br />
                                <a href="Javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:cancelConsult(@item.Ord_ID)" style="color:Red;">
                                    Cancel
                                    Consult
                                </a><br />
                            }
                        }
                 </text>).Title("Action Links");
             })  
               .Sortable() )  }
```

Comment: I tried to edit your question. The edit will be accepted in some short time. But I was not able to recover the code structure. Please paste it again and use the code tool to format it. Button looks like `{}`

Comment: Goodness it has been edited many times and yet the code still looks horrible. @sonu please consider to paste your code again to preserve our sanity

Answer (score 0):

you could check the [Migration guide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/migration/widgets/grid), that describes the differences between the Telerik and Kendo UI Grid. Looking at the code, it seems similar to the Grid in the [following demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding).